# Is it possible to split an xml file and do parallel processing of files in ABAP?

Tags: xml, parallel-processing, abap

I have an xml file containing many records. These records are used to update a custom table in SAP. Now my requirement is to split the file if the  number of records are greater than 60k and process each file separately. E.g.: If the number of records in xml file is 100k, then it should get split into two files of 60k and 40k and each file should be processed separately. I have done same type of things with csv files. I can split it and process it in parallel. But for xml files, it is very difficult. I am not able to do it. When I use open dataset in text mode and then use read dataset, then I can't read the file line by line. Again opening dataset in binary mode also fails. Please give me a logic to split the xml file. I am not able to do it.

My xml file is:

```
<Batch>
<header>
<system>ABC</system>
<time>20160428202244</time>
<user>a456</user>
<recver>5550458319J</recver>
<sender>29468422437</sender>
</header>
<status id="01006102739077803428">
<A>305430887B</A>
<B>2</B>
<C>20160404</C>
<D>Y</D>
<E>N</E>
<F>N</F>
<G>Y</G>
</status>
<status id="09007300449401352520">
<A>305449919L</A>
<B>2</B>
<C>20160404</C>
<D>N</D>
<E>Y</E>
<F>N</F>
<G>Y</G>
</status>
<trailer>
<numrecords>2</numrecords>
</trailer>
</Batch>
```

I have told that my file size is approx 0.2 GB. Now the file size may increase depending on the data extract. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to process large xml file by splitting into multiple xml files using open dataset in SAP ABAP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816848/how-to-process-large-xml-file-by-splitting-into-multiple-xml-files-using-open-da)

Comment: Please help me in it

Comment: How big is this file in megabytes/gigabytes?

Comment: File size is approx 200,000 KB i.e 0.2 GB

Comment: The xml file is in application server. I want to read the file and split it if number of records greater than 60k or any value. I just want to know the logic of splitting and then writing the xml into another file. Please help

Comment: 200 Mb is nothing. Write an XSL transformation and transform this XML stuff to CSV and then split it like you split your previous CSV files or use SAP extensions for XSLT to write the data directly into the table in your XSL transformation.

Comment: Actually I am a fresher and new in ABAP. Can you give one example of converting xml file into csv file?I don't know about XSL transformation.

Comment: Post some example records of your XML file, then I will be able to help you.

Comment: Jagger is right. (If you have REALLY big files, I'd use SAX to process the data. It allows to process terrabytes of data using a small main memory footprint. But this is not the case for your small data)

Comment: Please find the xml code that I have posted above. Please help me out. Also, file size may increase depending on the number of records.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start transaction `STRANS` and create a new transformation `ZTEST` (transformation type `X XSLT Program`).
2. Paste the following transformation and activate.

   ```
   <xsl:template match="Batch">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="header">
       <xsl:text>HEADER;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="system" />;<xsl:value-of select="time" />;<xsl:value-of select="user" />;<xsl:value-of select="recver" />;<xsl:value-of select="sender" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="status">
       <xsl:text>STATUS;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@id" />;<xsl:value-of select="A" />;<xsl:value-of select="B" />;<xsl:value-of select="C" />;<xsl:value-of select="D" />;<xsl:value-of select="E" />;<xsl:value-of select="F" />;<xsl:value-of select="G" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="trailer">
       <xsl:text>TRAILER;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="numrecords" />
   </xsl:template>
   ```
3. Start transaction `SXSLT` in order to test the transformation. Select the file from the presentation server and choose for example "Output to string".
4. Read the documentation on [`CALL TRANSFORMATION`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/abapcall_transformation.htm) in order to get familiar of how to process a file that is on the application server from your ABAP code.
5. Use your previous experiences on how to split CSV files.

Note that this will work only for files that are not greater than 500 Mb. For bigger files you might get runtime exceptions, because XSLT works on DOM trees that are loaded entirely into RAM.

Answer (score 0):

While XML parsing can be done in a multiple ways, I suppose using `OPEN DATASET` is your only option for reading files per se, and note [872457](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0000872457) recommends likewise.
 **GUI_UPLOAD** have a limit about 150 Mb, so the solution is to upload file to Application Server by FTP or by CG3Z/SXDA_TOOLS transactions, and then you will be able to use positional read (with adjustable chunk size) like this:

```
DATA fname(60) VALUE 'myfile'.
DATA num TYPE I VALUE 0.
DATA n TYPE I VALUE 100000.

DO n TIMES.
OPEN DATASET fname FOR INPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING DEFAULT AT POSITION num.
 IF sy-subrc NE 0.
  WRITE:/ 'error opening file'.
  EXIT.
 ELSE.
  WHILE ( sy-subrc EQ 0 ).
   READ DATASET v_file INTO wa_it_final.
   IF NOT wa_it_final IS INITIAL.
    APPEND wa_it_final TO it_final.
   ENDIF.
  CLEAR wa_it_final.
 ENDWHILE.
 ENDIF.
num = num + n.
ENDDO.
CLOSE DATASET file_str.
```